# I am trying to install a plugin but it gives an error

Tags: wordpress, plugins

[image]

When I activate this plugin it shows me the error how can i solve this?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function vc_add_shortcode_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\real\wp-content\plugins\realtyelite-theme-plugin\inc\vc-functions.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\real\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286): realtyelite_vc_custom_shortcodes('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\real\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\real\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\real\wp-admin\admin.php(156): do_action('admin_init') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\real\wp-admin\themes.php(10): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\real\wp-content\plugins\realtyelite-theme-plugin\inc\vc-functions.php on line 3

Comment: maybe this will help you, it's an old topic https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-add_shortcode_param/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Visual Composer is either disabled or not properly installed.